# Is there any reason for me to replay Shank on hard?

Tags: shank

Other than the bragging rights, will I gain anything for beating the single-player campaign of Shank on the harder of the two difficulties? Maybe a slightly different ending or some new costumes?

Comment: @tzenes Well.....yeah. But anything aside from that?

Comment: It's a video game... what more reason do you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, it seems the only difference between the single-player campaigns is difficulty.  However, there is also a co-operative campaign which follows a completely different story.  Purportedly, it's a prequel to the single-player campaign